# Transposed day and month values in MS Access 2007 when using Update Query in SQL View

Tags: database, vb.net

I have a challenge saving the date to an MS Access 2007 database especially for dates with the day less than the 12th of a month (i.e. the day between 01 to 11)  If for **example** a `February date - 07/02/2013 (dd/MM/yyyy)`  will be saved as `02/07/2013` in the database. While a similar February date `14/02/2013` will also be saved `14/02/2013`. Retrieving the two dates: The first date will brought out as 2nd July and the second date will be 14th February.

Notice that the day and month values is transposed for dates less than the 11th. This happens when I use an update query (either from VB 2005 or directly within MS Access using SQL pane). I have set both the system short date settings (in Windows 7 OS) and the Date Format at field level (in the MS Access Table) to **dd/MM/yyyy**.

Answer (score 0):

try - `DateValue("dd-mm-yyyy")`

or -  `Format(Date,"dd-mm-yyyy")` as an expression builder.